# If Cell B1 is "x", pull Cell A1, otherwise ignore

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Essentially, I'm trying to come up with a formula that only extracts data from rows where a condition in a separate column of the same row is met, the condition is a constant and I know the answer must be stupidly easy, but I can't figure it out.

Example, say you have array like so:

```
Name    Surname  Status
------  -------  ------
John    Bon      Green
Jane    Dane     Red
Alex    Flex     Yellow
Romeo   Cameo    Green
Boris   Horis    Green
Julius  Dubious  Yellow
Holy    Macaroni Green
```

And you wanted to have a list of people on a separate worksheet only with people with green status, without any blank rows in between when you drag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out, took forever.

```
     =IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("A" & SUM(MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A505, $A$1:$A$463),0),1)):$A$463,MATCH(1,COUNTIF($B$509,INDIRECT("K" & SUM(MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A505, $A$1:$A$463),0),1)):$K$463),0),),"")
```

LEGEND:

```
A505 = Previous result (Formula written in A506), Variable cell.

A1:A463 = Names

K1:K463 = Colours
```

The starting row of an Array will start 1 row below the previous result due to 'INDIRECT' formula.

From here it finds matching result to 'GREEN' in "K" Column represented by B509 and pulls how many rows below the starting row, then it uses row number in "A" Column to find the result that has "GREEN" as its colour.

If there's an error, it leaves the Cell Blank.

Answer (score 2):

If our data is in *Sheet1*, columns **A** through **C**, then in *Sheet2* cell **A1** we enter the criteria:

***Green***

Then in *Sheet1* cell **D2** we enter:

```
=IF(C2=Sheet2!$A$1,1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

This "Helper" column "marks" the rows of interest.

Then back on *Sheet2*, in **A2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Sheet1!D:D,0)),"")
```

and in **B2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Sheet1!D:D,0)),"")
```

Copy these cells downwards:

[image]